# How do I pass through values from an Elasticsearch document in Go?

Tags: json, go, elasticsearch

I'm experimenting with rewriting parts of our system in Go. They're currently written in Python. Some of the data that I want to serve lives in Elasticsearch.

Across our users, we have a few standard fields, but also allow people to create a number of custom fields specific to their environment. E.g., we have a product object that has some common fields like `name` and `price`, but we let someone create a field like `discount_price` or `requires_freight` to agree with their use case.

In Python, this is easy to accommodate. The JSON is read in, our chosen JSON parser does some reasonable type inference, and we can then return the data after it's processed.

In Go, any data we want to deal with from the Elasticsearch JSON response has to be mapped to a type. Or at least that's my understanding. For example:

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
)

...

type Product struct {
    Name              string   `json:"name"`
    Price             string   `json:"price"`
}
```

Here's a simplified example of what the data might look like. I've prefixed the names of the nonstandard fields I'd want to pass through with `custom`:

```
{
    "id": "ABC123",
    "name": "Great Product",
    "price": 10.99,
    "custom_alternate_names": ["Great Product"],
    "custom_sellers": [{
        "id": "ABC123",
        "name": "Great Product LLC",
        "emails": ["great@stuff.com"]
    }]
}
```

It would be fine to special case for places where the route actually needs to process or manipulate a custom field. But in most cases, passing through the JSON data unchanged is fine, so the fact we aren't imposing any type mappings for safety isn't adding anything.

Is there a way to set up the `struct` with an interface (?) that could act as a passthrough for any unmapped fields? Or a way to take the unparsed JSON data and recombine it with the mapped object before the data are returned?

Comment: You can use `json.RawMessage` for data that you only want to write/read and don't need to manipulate and/or validate. For custom fields that you do need to manipulate you can use a map or a slice, and the map's/slice's element type could be a struct with 3 members fieldName, fieldType, fieldValue for example.

Comment: That's very helpful. How would I then add the catchall to the struct? Sorry if that's a silly question — I'm fairly new to Go.

Comment: Depends on the json, are the custom fields at the same level (nesting) as the non-custom ones, e.g. `{"name":"...","price":"...","custom_field1":"...","custom_field2":"..."}`? Or are they grouped together and nested under some pre-defined field, i.e. `{"name":"...","price":"...","custom":{"field1":"...","field2":"..."}}`? Or is it more complex? If you can, update the question by adding an example of the json you would like to handle.

Comment: The nesting is non-uniform, but it can only go two levels deep, I think. I'll dig up a shareable example and update the question.

Comment: Added what I think is a pretty representative example to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

type Product struct {
    //embed product to be able to pull the properties without
    //requiring a nested object in the json
    KnownFields
    OtherStuff json.RawMessage
}

//Custom unmarshaller
func (p *Product) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var k KnownFields
    //unmarshal the known fields
   err := json.Unmarshal(b, &k)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    p.KnownFields = k
    //You can use json.RawMessage or map[string]interface
    p.OtherStuff = json.RawMessage(b)
    return nil
}

type KnownFields struct {
    Name  string      `json:"name"`
    Price json.Number `json:"price"`
}

const JSON = `
{
    "id": "ABC123",
    "name": "Great Product",
    "price": 10.99,
    "custom_alternate_names": ["Great Product"],
    "custom_sellers": [{
        "id": "ABC123",
        "name": "Great Product LLC",
        "emails": ["great@stuff.com"]
    }]
}`

func main() {
    var p Product
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(JSON), &p)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    log.Printf("%v", p)
}
```

If you are going to mutate and marshall the `Product` you will have to implement a custom marshaller and also you would need to use `map[string]interface{}` as the `OtherStuff` to avoid having duplicate entries for the known fields